# Calculating variance upon removing a value from the sample

Tags: statistics, means, variance

We are given that a sample of $N=7$ has mean $\bar{X} = 5$, and a sample variance of $s^2 = 9$. One person, with a score of $11$ is removed from the data. What is the mean and variance for the new set of scores?

We can quite easily compute $\mu_{new} = 4$, but $s_{new}^2$ is a slightly more tedious to calculate.

Here's my approach, where I make the assumption that the $7$th score is $X_7 = 11$.
$$
63 = \sum_{i=1}^7 (X-5)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^6(X-5)^2 + 36
$$
So that tells us that $\sum_{i=1}^6(X-5)^2 = 27$.

$$
27 = \sum_{i=1}^6(X^2 - 10x + 25) = \sum_{i=1}^6 X^2 -10 \sum_{i=1}^6 X + 150 \\
-123 + 2\sum_{i=1}^6 X + 96 = \sum_{i=1}^6 X^2 -8 \sum_{i=1}^6 X + 96 \\
-27 + 2\sum_{i=1}^6 X = 21 = \sum_{i=1}^6(X-4)^2
$$

Now, we divide each side by 5 and the RHS becomes $s_{new}^2$, and the left becomes $4.2$.

That is apparently not the correct answer. The answer should be $2.4$.

Comment: Your working looks fine. I suspect there is a typo in the answers. Transcribing the two digits in typing would be an easy mistake to make.

Comment: I stand corrected. I missed the word **sample** in sample variance. This change your working.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Sample Variance is bias corrected.

$$\begin{align}s^2 =~& \frac 1{\color{purple}{n-1}}\sum_{k=1}^n \left(X_k-\frac 1 n\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\right)^2
\\  =~& \frac 1 {n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k^2-\frac n {(n-1)}\bar X^2
\end{align}$$

So substituting then rearranging: $$\begin{align}9 =~& \tfrac 1 6(11^2+\sum_{k=1}^6X_k^2)-\tfrac 76 (5^2)
\\ 6(9) =~& 11^2+\sum_{k=1}^6 X_k^2-7(5^2)
\\ \tfrac 1 5\sum_{k=1}^6 X_k^2 -\tfrac 6 5 (4^2) =~& \tfrac 65(9)-\tfrac 1 511^2+\tfrac 75(5^2)-\tfrac 6 5 (4^2) 
\\ s_{\rm new}^2 =~& \tfrac {12}5
\\ =~& 2.4
\end{align}$$